# Solve the following for $T$ in terms of time generally $\tau_T \frac{dT}{dt}= -T + ca(t)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

$\tau_T \frac{dT}{dt}= -T + ca(t)$

$\frac{dT}{dt}= \frac{-T}{\tau_t} + \frac{ca(t)}{\tau_t}$

$dT= \frac{-T}{\tau_T} dt + \frac{ca(t)}{\tau_T} dt$

$\int dT = \frac{-1}{\tau_T} \int T(t) dt + \frac{c}{\tau_T} \int a(t) dt$

T is the threat level t is the time and $\tau$ is the constraint

I want to be able to write the last line to solve for T for a function in terms of time as a general solution. I don't know what the other functions are though explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
 \frac{dT}{dt} + \frac{1}{\tau_T}T =  \frac{c}{\tau_T}a(t),
$$
and multiply by $ e^{t/ \tau_T}$
$$
e^{t/ \tau_T}\left(\frac{dT}{dt} + \frac{1}{\tau_T}T\right)=\frac{c}{\tau_T}a(t)e^{t/ \tau_T}
$$
Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/ \tau_T}T(t)\right)=\frac{c}{\tau_T}a(t)e^{t/ \tau_T}
$$
Integrating both members and dividing by $e^{-t/ \tau_T} $
$$
 T(t) =\frac{c}{\tau_T}e^{-t/ \tau_T}\left(\int_0^t a(s)e^{s/ \tau_T}\, ds+C\right)
$$
where $C$ is an integration constant.

Comment: Thank you for your timely response! It is not obvious to me how you get from the 3rd to the 4th step. Also, what is s and ds?

Comment: You integrate both members (recall: if you integrate $f(t)$ in $dt$, you write $\int_0^t f(s) ds $, the integration variable is a "dumb" variable); then you divide by $ e^{-t/\tau}$ in order to make $T(t)$ explicit